# Programatically change the title text of my AppCompatActivity SupportActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

Why does this seem so difficult to accomplish? I have a condition in which I want to dynamically change the action bar of my activity.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.voted_on_by));
```

Why doesn't this change the title of my action bar to the string I want?

In onCreate I do this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

assert getSupportActionBar() != null;

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: have you added toolbar in your activity ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this

```
((MainActivity) this).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.voted_on_by);
```

or

```
((AppCompatActivity)this).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("sub categories");
```

Comment: It still shows the title text set in my XML. Does it not override?

Comment: If you have put toolbar in XML you need to find tool bar by od and set title over it.

Comment: You can use toolbar.setTitle("");